# What are reliable ways to identify/spot a single page application (SPA)?

Tags: single-page-application

When viewing a web application as a user, what are some reliable ways to determine if the app is a single page application (SPA)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in the [faq]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the framework used, the URL *might* make extensive use of hashtags.  IF you click on navigation links, etc and the URL looks like http://somesite/#/some/route, then it is using hashtag-based routing and is a SPA.  Angular 1.x did this for a while.  However, newer routing engines use HTML5 features that make the route look like a normal URL: http://somesite/some/route.  This URL would be indistinguishable from a non-SPA site.  In that case, the only way to tell it is a SPA is to look at the javascript code (Does it use a SPA framework) and/or network traffic (when you click a link does it get the whole page, or just some JSON needed for the current view).

Comment: In Chrome's developer tools, under network, it would typically read "xhr" under type.  If you click the row and look at Headers, Content-Type would typically read "application/json".  Under Preview or Response it would show what looks like JSON.  Note this only applies if the SPA is getting JSON data.  If it _doesn't_ load a new page (type=document, content-type=text/html), then it is most likely a SPA.